# Running Jenkins integration test without having to rebuild with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Im having some problems understanding how Jenkins interact with Maven to create simple build pipleines. For example lets say I want to do to following pipeline:

```
1 Compile code, run unittest, and package to code.
2 Deploy application to test server.
3 Run integration tests.
```

This would translate to:

```
1 mvh clean install
2 deploy.sh
3 mvn verify
```

For my unittests I use surefire and for integration test I use failsafe. However the problem is that `mvn verify` will do the whole build process all over again. What I want to do is just run the integration tests and not all the steps leading up to verify. What are the standard way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The maven way of doing this is to do it all using maven. The default maven build lifecycle has a phase for each of the steps you want to do: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

> For example, the default lifecycle comprises of the following phases
>   (for a complete list of the lifecycle phases, refer to the Lifecycle
>   Reference):
>
> validate - validate the project is correct and all necessary
>   information is available
>
> compile - compile the source code of the
>   project
>
> test - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit
>   testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged
>   or deployed
>
> package - take the compiled code and package it in its
>   distributable format, such as a JAR.
>
> integration-test - process and
>   deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration
>   tests can be run
>
> verify - run any checks to verify the package is
>   valid and meets quality criteria
>
> install - install the package into
>   the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects
>   locally
>
> deploy - done in an integration or release environment, copies
>   the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other
>   developers and projects.

So you want to deploy the artifacts to your test server (your step 2) as part of the integration-test phase. Then all you have to do is run

```
mvn clean install
```

This will clean and then do all you building, running unit tests, packaging it all up, deploy to the integration environment, run your integration tests and install the artifacts in your local repository.

Comment: But what if I want to have dependencies on other Jenkin builds. For example i dont want to run the integration tests until some other build is done? Then I would still have the problem I described above?

Comment: Maven always runs the phases up to and including the phase you ask for. If you want to have jenkins orchestrating multiple maven projects, all you need to do is specify the dependencies in jenkins. I think that the specific answer you may be looking for is that you will want to put your integration tests into a different maven module so when you "mvn verify" it is just going to build your test classes and run your integration tests with the failsafe plugin. Obviously, the integration test module will depend on the maven module that contains the actual functionality.